# Can one use the S3 APIs in the Java AWS SDK with a private server exposing the S3 interface?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, jclouds

I would like to connect to a server that exposes the S3 interface. I am currently using [jclouds](https://jclouds.apache.org/). And I would like to check other alternatives. Does the [Java AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) work with private servers? (I don't get it from the documentation for example what the [`ClientConfiguration.setNonProxyHosts()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#setNonProxyHosts-java.lang.String-) does; can I specify which server the client connects to?).

If AWS SDK is not working, what other alternatives are there for jclouds (that can connect to a private S3 server)

Answer (score 1):

You can try Minio Client [java-sdk](https://github.com/minio/minio-java) libraries, it is compatible with AWS S3 signature v4 and open source.

API-Doc: https://github.com/minio/minio-java/blob/master/docs/API.md

Examples: https://github.com/minio/minio-java/tree/master/examples

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://minio.io)

Comment: Can Minio client talk to S3 through a proxy?

Comment: I constantly get a `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` when I use the minio client. Check this Gist out: https://gist.github.com/gabipetrovay/d2b242108e61f7a2ff851500d5153719

Comment: Minio is not meant to be S3 proxy, it is a fully standalone S3 alternative.  Do you have more information on the example? not able to reproduce the problem that you mentioned. Able to access the server just fine.

Comment: minio-java uses java.nio.file which isn‘t provied in Android Java 1.6 based API,  @koolhead17